# For Loop having three statements

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is this possible? 1 for loop 3 statements?

```
    for(var i =0; i< aObj.length;i++)
(var a =0; a< bObj.length;a++)
(var b =0; b< cObj.length;b++){
         //sOME CODE HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is invalid javascript syntax. Depending on your requirements you could either use 3 nested for loops or make them sequential.

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
    for(var a = 0; a < bObj.length; a++) {
        for(var b = 0; b < cObj.length; b++) {
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
for(var i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
    // some code here
}

for(var a = 0; a < bObj.length; a++) {
    // some code here
}

for(var b = 0; b < cObj.length; b++) {
    // some code here
}
```

But once again it will depend on what exactly you need to do with those variables.

Comment: I have 3 diffrent loop to get every data in xml. but it didnt get the every data. its get the last,that's why I asked if thats possible. its my codes of Loops to get the data Name.Code and Category and out in Listview

Comment: $(req.responseText).find('Name').each(function(){ 
        NameObj[Nameindex] = $(this).text();
         Nameindex +=0;
                             
        for(var i =0; i< NameObj.length;i++){
         $(this).append(NameObj[i]+"<br/>");
     } 
                                           
) //first loop

Comment: $(req.responseText).find('Code').each(function(){ 
                  CodeObj[Codeindex] = $(this).text();
                  Codeindex +=0;
                                    
                for(var a =0; a< CodeObj.length;a++){
                      $(this).append(CodeObj[a]+"<br/>");
                 } 
                             
                });//2nd loop

Comment: $(req.responseText).find('Category').each(function(){ 
                CatObj[Catindex] = $(this).text();
              Catindex +=0;
              for(var b =0; b< CatObj.length;b++){
                $(this).append(CatObj[b]+"<br/>");
                      } 
            });//3rd loop

Comment: var $content = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/album-bb.jpg"><h3>Name: '+ NameObj[i] + '</h3><p>Code: '+ CodeObj[a] + '</p><p>Category: '+  CatObj[b] + '</p></a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add to favorites</a></li>');                              
$('#RecipeList').append($content).listview('refresh');//My codes for append to list view

Comment: the problem is the last items each loop is put in the list view. My xml have a 100 items. but it put 1 items only in listview

Comment: @Keen-EGS you should put all that code in your original post as an edit, pretty hard to read it in the comments.

Comment: I put in now sir. Its one of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think tat is not possible better go for:

```
for(var i =0; i< aObj.length;i++){
  for(var a =0; a< bObj.length;a++){
   for(var b =0; b< cObj.length;b++){
   //sOME CODE HERE
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my actual Code guys..Im getting the last items for Name,Code and Category not per items in array

```
var CodeObj=new Array(); var NameObj=new Array(); new aObj = new Array();
var CatObj=new Array(); var Codeindex= 0;
var Nameindex= 0; var Catindex= 0; aindex = 0; 


    $(req.responseText).find('Name').each(function(){ 
                             NameObj[Nameindex] = $(this).text();
                             Nameindex +=0;

                         for(var i =0; i< NameObj.length;i++){
                              $(this).append(NameObj[i]+"<br/>");
                           } //1st loop to get the Name

     }) 

    $(req.responseText).find('Code').each(function(){ 
                   CodeObj[Codeindex] = $(this).text();
                    Codeindex +=0;
                  for(var a =0; a< CodeObj.length;a++){
                        $(this).append(CodeObj[a]+"<br/>");

                  } //2nd loop to get the Code

     });


     $(req.responseText).find('Category').each(function(){ 
                          CatObj[Catindex] = $(this).text();
                          Catindex +=0;
                    for(var b =0; b< CatObj.length;b++){
                                $(this).append(CatObj[b]+"<br/>");

                    } //3rd loop to get the category
            });
   //codes to append in list view                            
       var $content = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/album-bb.jpg"><h3>Name: '+ NameObj[i] + '</h3><p>Code: '+ CodeObj[a] + '</p><p>Category: '+  CatObj[b] + '</p></a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add to favorites</a></li>');                              
      $('#RecipeList').append($content).listview('refresh');
```

Comment: post this in ur question as an update